# Probability involving two Erlang random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, definite-integrals, recurrence-relations, poisson-process

I have two independent random variables $X,Y$ such that $X\sim\operatorname{Erl}(n,\lambda)$ and $Y\sim\operatorname{Erl}(m,\mu)$. I am trying to find the probability $P(X<Y)$.

I started with the following 
\begin{align}
P(X<Y)&=\int_{0}^{\infty}P(X<Y|X=x)P(X=x)dx\\
      &=\int_{0}^{\infty}P(Y>x)P(X=x)dx
\end{align}

After simplification, I am stuck and  unable to get a closed form for the above integral. But I got a hint that a recursive form exists: if $P(X<Y)=G(n,m)$ then 
$$(\lambda+\mu)G(n,m)=\lambda G(n-1,m)+ \mu G(n,m-1)$$
I tried to evaluate the above integral by parts, considering the integrand as a product of two functions dependent on $n$ and $m$. But the problem still persists. Now I wondered: can I proceed to show the recurrence relation by taking $$X=X_1+X_2+ \dots +X_n$$
$$Y=Y_1+Y_2+ \dots +Y_m$$
where $X_i\sim\exp(\lambda)$ and $Y_j\sim\exp(\mu)$? Am I approaching correctly or is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something along the following lines (not checked):

Starting with $\displaystyle P(X<Y)=\int_{0}^{\infty}P(Y\ge x\mid X=x)\,p(x)\,dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}P(Y\ge x)\,p(x)\,dx$ since you have independence

you know $p(x) = \dfrac{\lambda^n x^{n-1} e^{-\lambda x}}{(n-1)!\,}$ and  $\displaystyle P(Y\ge x) = \sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\frac{1}{k!}e^{-\mu x}(\mu x)^{k}$

so $\displaystyle P(X<Y)=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \dfrac{\lambda^n \mu^k}{(n-1)!\,k!}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-(\lambda+\mu) x}x^{k+n-1}\,dx=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} {k+n-1 \choose n-1}\dfrac{\lambda^n \mu^k }{(\lambda+\mu)^{k+n}}$ which may have a further simplification

Comment: Can you elaborate the last step?

Comment: @mea43  You can use $\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty} x^a \, e^{-bx} \, dx = \dfrac{\Gamma(b)}{a^b}$